# Visual Studio Solution Explorer "Do Not Enter" Symbol Meaning?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2015

A Visual Studio solution I've opened for the first time is showing me files with a "Do Not Enter" symbol.  What does it mean?

[image]

Despite the odd symbol, Visual Studio allows me to interact with the files in a normal fashion.

I've opened windows explorer as well, and also noticed something funny:

[image]

Some of the files above have a "grayed-out" file icon.  Here are things I've checked:

- They are not system files
- They are not hidden files
- I do have full ownership of the files (as demonstrated by `dir /q`)
- They are not read-only files

So what the heck is making both Visual Studio and Windows Explorer think something is "funny" about these files?

Comment: That's probably a source control status indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same behavior and I have it because I generate the solution(with the projects) to the *bin* subfolder which is listed in the git ignore file. So MSVS shows this little red icon meaning that all my projects are ignored by git.

Since you have the cmake tag in the question I'm pretty sure you have the same situation.